# Can we use Google Custom Search API cheaper?

Tags: api, google-search-api

We need to have a Keyword Tracker for Google. We actually have, however the cost is an issue.

There's the [SheerSEO](http://www.sheerseo.com/) which is based on a tracker like that and they seem to provide Keyword Tracking service cheaper than Google. Although we are not doing a new SheerSEO, we have to fetch keywords from Google.

**SheerSEO**

- 400 keywords for $15/mo.
- Refreshes weekly
- Fetches first 20 page for each keyword
- [Pricing page](http://www.sheerseo.com/seo-monitoring-tools/pricing.html)

Monthly keyword cost is $15/400 = $0.0375 and the company benefits from this too. 
So I assume they earn at least the half of the money (it should be more though).

With this assumption: **~$0.019 for per keyword monthly**

**Google Custom Search** (for searching entire web, not specific domains)

- Costs $5 per 1000 queries.
- Doesn't give more than 1 page (10 results) for a single query.
- [Pricing page (at the bottom)](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/overview#Pricing)

Applying SheerSEO limits:

Every keyword needs 20 queries for the first 20 pages, weekly, that is 80 queries monthly.

1000 / 80 = 12.5 keywords monthly for $5

For each keyword it is $5/12.5 = **$0.4/mo**

We thought of using SheerSEO API but they don't allow adding keywords with API, keywords have to be added manually.

Can we make our cost as cheap as SheerSEO or in other terms how can they do it? Are there any other Google service we are overlooking? Google Custom Search API is 21 times more expensive than SheerSEO.

Answer (score 1):

I'm thinking this is off topic, but my guess would be that most clients don't actually track 400 keywords.

Also, you get 100 free queries per day, which amounts to 3000 free queries per month.  So my guess is they are taking advantage of that as well.

Comment: Come on it is not an off-topic, there's even a "tag" for google-search-api. And there's defintely an answer, however I'm fine to settle with a close answer. Google Custom Search API is so expensive, I just need to cut the expenses and I'm looking for a way.

Comment: What about now? I've changed the title and focused on Google API more and less on SheerSEO.

Answer (score 0):

You're comparing apples and oranges. Google Custom Search is intended to be embedded into a web site to create a custom search engine — it is not built for automated use. Indeed, the [Terms of Service for Google Custom Search](http://www.google.com/cse/docs/tos.html) would specifically prohibit you from using it for a keyword tracker:

> **1.4 Appropriate Conduct.** You shall not, and shall not allow any third party to: [...] (f) directly or indirectly access, launch and/or activate the Service [*Google Custom Search*] through or from, or otherwise incorporate the Service in, any Web site or other means other than the Site [*a web site embedding the Google Custom Search widget to display search results*].

There are a number of other subsections of section 1.4 which would prohibit this use, but that's one of the more obviously worded ones. Point is, it's not a tool for gathering SEO information.

Comment: So how does SheerSEO get the Keyword information? Also Google Custom Search allows the search for entire web and gives JSON results and gives it both for client-side and server-side access (you can obtain 2 different keys). I think that TOS 1.4 is not for this, I think it is for "sharing the service with 3rd party users" and we do not share the service.

Comment: I don't know how SheerSEO is working. The entirety of 1.4 is pretty clear to me, though: Custom Search is for building custom searches, not analyzing search results.